# How to access png image to byte array in Unity?

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, byte, decode

I am a starter of Unity developer,
I have an image file saved in the device,
the file path shown as follow:

```
string filePath = Application.persistenceDataPath + "myImage.png";
```

How can I decode it to be byte array so that I can use it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Use it for ... do you need it to be a byte array or do you just want to use it as an image/texture in your application?

Comment: If this is a file on the user's machine, you could "download" it using a [WWW object](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html), then load the texture via [`WWW.texture`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html). If this is a file you include with the build, you should probably instead use the [Resources class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved! Thank you for helps! I have found the answer that absolutely what I need.

```
byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

Therefore, I can use it any where.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the bytes in a `byteArray` variable, you can do:

```
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height);
    tex.LoadImage(byteArray);
    renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
```

But to load from a file, you can use `Resources.Load` if it's inside a `Resources` folder, or `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload` if it's not, but them it will have to be an *asset bundle* instead of an image, and to build an asset bundle you'll need Unity Pro. Notice that WWW doesn't require the `url` to **be** an URL, it can be a path. See examples here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload.html

So, to sum up you first load the image into a byte array and then you use the `Texture2D` class to load the bytes into a texture object.